# How to receive message from an actor in non actor class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, akka.net

I'm using an actor system to calculate some data, and then I want it to return the result from not originally asked actor endpoint to my non actor oriented program. I tried using `Ask` or `Ask<>` with `await` or `Result` but it didn't help either.
This is a simplified example of what I want to achieve:

```
class Program
{
    public static ActorSystem actorSystem;
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("ActorSystem");
        var mainActor = actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new MainActor()), "main");
        var actorAnswer = await mainActor.Ask<object[]>(new Start(true));
        //Some operations using actorAnswer from actor ...
    }
}
```

And simplified MainActor:

```
class MainActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public MainActor()
    {
        Receive<Start>(m =>
        {
            _commanderActor.Tell(new SomeMessage());
        });
        Receive<IEnumerable<int[]>>(m => 
        {
            if (condition)
            {                                                     
                Sender.Tell(new object[] {x, y});
            }
            else
            {
                _commanderActor.Tell(new SomeMessage());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I your actor's `Start` receiver, you're not sending response back to Sender.

Comment: So when I send message to `Receive<Start>` I can't send the response from `Receive<IEnumerable<int[]>>` ? Then how can I get data from this actor when he finishes.

Comment: You can, except that in the code you presented there's no workflow that shows that. Also keep in mind that `Sender` property is changing over time, so you need to store it somewhere if you want to refer to it later. Sender inside of `Receive<IEnumerable<int[]>>` handler points to an actor which had sent `IEnumerable<int[]>` message, which in your case is probably **NOT** an Ask method from your main thread.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think of it that way. With this advice I resolved my problem. I had to save `Sender` reference to field in `Receive<Start>` section and then use this reference in `Receive<IEnumerable<int[]>>` to send data back to `Main` function. Thanks Bartosz